# Use bootstrap pagination and jquery to swap divs in a page

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use Bootstrap pagination on my webpage. Based on everything avaliable online I have come up with the following piece of code thats taken from what's available online. What I need is to be able to swap divs on the same page. The problem in this script occurs early wherein my currentpage variable is undefined and am also not able to find the activePage. I have used `$(".pagination-container").data('page')` and also `$(this).data('page')` and both return undefined. I'll be greatful if someone can have a look at the script and give necessary pointers as to how to make it work.

```
<script>
var paginationHandler = function(){
  $('.page_control li').unbind('click', paginationHandler);
  var currentPage   = $(this).data('page');
      var   activePage   = $(this).parent().find('.active').data('page');
        var num_elements   = $(this).parent().children().length;
// This equals the first data-page value after the < button.
        var start    = 1;
 // This is the end of the actual pages, remember it is offset by the < and > buttons.
        var end     = num_elements-2;
  if(currentPage === '+' ){
      (activePage < end) ? currentPage = activePage + 1 : currentPage = start;
  }

  if(currentPage === '-'){
      (activePage > start) ? currentPage = activePage - 1 : currentPage = end;
  }
// Remove the active class to the li
  $(this).parent().find('.active').removeClass('active');

// Add the active class to the appropriate li taking
          $(this).parent().find('li[data-page*=' + currentPage + ']').addClass('active');

$(this).parents("div .pagination-container").find('div[data-page*=' + activePage + ']').fadeOut('fast', function(){
       $(this).parents("div .pagination-container").find('div[data-page*=' + currentPage + ']').fadeIn('fast');
  $('.page_control li').bind('click', paginationHandler);
  });
};
$( document ).ready( paginationHandler );
</script>
```

And here's my HTML:

```
<div class="pagination-container" >
<div data-page="1" >
      <p>Content for Div Number 1</p>
   </div>
   <div data-page="2" style="display:none;">
      <p>Content for Div Number 2</p>
   </div>
   <div data-page="3" style="display:none;">
      <p>Content for Div Number 3</p>
   </div>
   <div data-page="4" style="display:none;">
      <p>Content for Div Number 4</p>
   </div>
   <div data-page="5" style="display:none;">
      <p>Content for Div Number 5</p>
   </div>

   <div class="pagination pagination-centered pagination-large" style="position:absolute; bottom:0;">
       <ul class="page_control ">
            <li data-page="-" ><a href="#" >&lt;</a></li>
            <li class="active" data-page="1">
                <a href="#" >1</a>
            </li>
            <li data-page="2"><a href="#" >2</a></li>
            <li data-page="3"><a href="#" >3</a></li>
            <li data-page="4"><a href="#" >4</a></li>
            <li data-page="5"><a href="#" >5</a></li>
            <li data-page="+"><a href="#" >&gt;</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the adjusted script based on your HTML structure.

```
<script>
var paginationHandler = function(){
    // store pagination container so we only select it once
    var $paginationContainer = $(".pagination-container"),
        $pagination = $paginationContainer.find('.pagination ul');

    // click event
    $pagination.find("li a").on('click.pageChange',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        // get parent li's data-page attribute and current page
        var parentLiPage = $(this).parent('li').data("page"),
            currentPage = parseInt( $(".pagination-container div[data-page]:visible").data('page') ),
            numPages = $paginationContainer.find("div[data-page]").length;

        // make sure they aren't clicking the current page
        if ( parseInt(parentLiPage) !== parseInt(currentPage) ) {
            // hide the current page
            $paginationContainer.find("div[data-page]:visible").hide();

            if ( parentLiPage === '+' ) {
                // next page
                $paginationContainer.find("div[data-page="+( currentPage+1>numPages ? numPages : currentPage+1 )+"]").show();
            } else if ( parentLiPage === '-' ) {
                // previous page
                $paginationContainer.find("div[data-page="+( currentPage-1<1 ? 1 : currentPage-1 )+"]").show();
            } else {
                // specific page
                $paginationContainer.find("div[data-page="+parseInt(parentLiPage)+"]").show();
            }

        }
    });
};
$( document ).ready( paginationHandler );
</script>
```

Here's a JS Fiddle to show it working: https://jsfiddle.net/x2tqujzz/2/

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks for the answer. Its missing a semi-colon on line 3rd from bottom and ')' on the line above. Also it doesnt swap the divs rather show all the divs that are clicked on. I am really looking for pointers as to what's wrong with my code.

Comment: The current page div is hidden with `$paginationContainer.find("div[data-page="+currentPage+"]").hide();`. There were several problems with the code you're trying to use. The `$(this).parent().find('.active').data('page')` wouldn't find the active page, because it's selected the parent li, and if that's not active, then it won't find the active page. The `$(this).parents("div .pagination-container")` will not be found because of the space between `div` and `.pagination-container`.

Comment: You're also doing too many selections of DOM elements instead of just selecting once, and handling that object, so the code I wrote will work significantly faster than what you have (if what you have would work to begin with).

Comment: You're also unbinding the built-in binding on the pagination li's which defeats the purpose of using the Bootstrap pagination component because it has some useful built-in JS that adds/removes the active class from the items as you click them.

Comment: Did you try swapping in my code? Just curious if it really doesn't work for you - I'm certainly happy to adjust it as needed. My approach is definitely more standard jQuery than what you're trying to do up there..

Comment: Thanks.But I cant seem to get you script to work. It displays the different divs rather than replacing them. You can even try in codepen to see what I mean

Comment: I adjusted my code, and made a JS Fiddle to show it in action. Let me know how that works for you!

Comment: The arrows keys work now. But clicking on a particular page link makes the div vanish completely

Comment: Btw i cant thank you enough for your help :) and I should be able to hopefully figure out the problem

Comment: The problem was an extra tab in the data-page selector for that particular case (I accidentally added them when I was pasting the response in from JS Fiddle where it was working correctly). I've adjusted my answer to fix it.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please select it as your chosen answer :) It helps me out with my capabilities to help others here.

Comment: Hmm. I didnt even know that indentation mattered. It works though. Thanks a bunch

Comment: Yeah, it was in the middle of the selector lol - the line breaks in the editor on here made me think that it was its own line, so I added spaces and it broke the selector ( `$("div[data-  page=....]` doesn't work), so it didn't select, and didn't show the div.

Comment: "Active" class is not being handled now so UI doesnt show/remove which "page" we are looking at

Answer (score 1):

Updated to include navigation UI selector active status

```
var paginationHandler = function(){
  // store pagination container so we only select it once
  var $paginationContainer = $(".pagination-container"),
      $pagination = $paginationContainer.find('.pagination ul');

  // click event
  $pagination.find("li a").on('click.pageChange',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

      // get parent li's data-page attribute and current page
      var parentLiPage = $(this).parent('li').data("page"),
          currentPage = parseInt( $(".pagination-container div[data-page]:visible").data('page') ),
          numPages = $paginationContainer.find("div[data-page]").length;

      // make sure they aren't clicking the current page
      if ( parseInt(parentLiPage) !== parseInt(currentPage) ) {
          // hide the current page
          $paginationContainer.find("div[data-page]:visible").hide();
          
          // update UI
          $('.pagination ul li.active').removeClass('active');          

          if ( parentLiPage === '+' ) {
            var nextPage = (currentPage+1 == numPages+1) ? currentPage : currentPage+1;
            $paginationContainer.find("li[data-page="+nextPage+"]").addClass('active');

            $paginationContainer.find("div[data-page="+( nextPage>numPages ? numPages : nextPage )+"]").show();              

          } else if ( parentLiPage === '-' ) {
            var prevPage = (0 == currentPage-1) ? currentPage : currentPage-1;
            $paginationContainer.find("li[data-page="+prevPage+"]").addClass('active');
            $paginationContainer.find("div[data-page="+( prevPage<1 ? 1 : prevPage )+"]").show();

          } else {
              // specific page
              $paginationContainer.find("div[data-page="+parseInt(parentLiPage)+"]").show();
              $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
          }
      }
  });
};
$( document ).ready( paginationHandler );
```